# Year selection in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery

hey guys, m using JQuery UI Datepicker for my form and my script is like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
          $("#<%=txtExpiryDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({changeYear:"true"});
    });
</script>
```

But this shows only Month selection as prev/next button but i want Year selection also so i use'd `.datepicker(changeYear:"true")` but this gives a comboBox i want prev/next button like "Month" has got...... where n what tweaks have to be done ?

Comment: so you want year to also have a next/prev buttons?

Comment: I thing that you must code it yourself by extending datepicker.

Answer (score 5):

That gives a syntax error. Also, `true` should be passed as a boolean literal, not a string. Looking for this?

```
$(function() {
    $("#").datepicker({changeYear: true});
});
```

### EDIT

Does this do what you want?

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [3, 4],
    stepMonths: 12
});​
```

Comment: `but this gives a comboBox i want prev/next button like "Month" has got...... where n what tweaks have to be done ?` - what do you not understand by this? ;)

Comment: m absolutely sorry for that syntax error.. but this function will shows a dropdown box for year selection but i want next/prev button for changing the year.

Comment: that was nice dear, but i'm expecting 2 buttons for changing the year, for a timebeing im gonna use above code thanx man.

Comment: @FosterZ: You're gonna have to rewrite the datepicker code if you want it to work in any other way

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post, but I came across this issue so I decided to let an answer if any one need it.

```
$('.year-picker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    stepMonths: 12,
    beforeShow: function() {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("year-picker");
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 0, 1));
    }
});
```

css:

```
.year-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar,.year-picker .ui-datepicker-month{
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you, although its an old post but it definitely gonna help someone. And a link to working jsfiddle would be very helpful though.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

here try this

```
  <script src="js/jsDatepicker/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="js/jsDatepicker/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>--%>
    <link href="js/jsDatepicker/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jsDatepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("[id$=txtFrom]").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "1990:2100"
            });  });
    </script>
```

Comment: u can decide the range start and end